# How to calculate using items in a CSV based on selection from first column?

Tags: c#, list, forms, visual-studio, csv

Hello my program is a postage calculator and I have the weights of parcels in one column and then the cost in the 2nd column. the user selects their weight from a drop-down list and I want to then calculate i.e weight.selected index from column 1 * column 2 equivalent. ill be doing the same with the 3rd column

the csv is

20kg    £16.50  £23.80

35kg    £29.40  £36.20

60kg    £41.60  £45.10

85kg    £52.40  £61.20

100kg   £66.20  £74.80

100kg+  0.65    0.8

e.g. user selects 20kg as their parcel weight I want to set £16.50 as the total cost

input form code

```
namespace ParcelDelivery
{
    public partial class Postage : Form
    {
    List<string> weight = new List<string>();
    List<string> StandardUK = new List<string>();
    List<string> SurfaceEU = new List<string>();
    public Postage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("PostageCost.csv");
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
            String[] values = line.Split(',');

            cBxWeightUk.Items.Add(values[0]);
            cBxWeightEU.Items.Add(values[0]);
            StandardUK.Add(values[1]);
            SurfaceEU.Add(values[2]);

        }
        reader.Close(); //close the csv file

        gBxDeliveryEU.Visible = false;
        gBxPostageDetsEU.Visible = false;
        gBxDeliveryUK.Visible = false;
        gBxPostDetsUK.Visible = false;
        gBxInsurance.Visible = false;
    }

    private void rBtnUK_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gBxDeliveryEU.Visible = false;
        gBxPostageDetsEU.Visible = false;
        gBxDeliveryUK.Visible = true;
        gBxPostDetsUK.Visible = true;
        gBxInsurance.Visible = true;
    }

    private void rBtnEU_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gBxDeliveryUK.Visible = false;
        gBxPostDetsUK.Visible = false;
        gBxDeliveryEU.Visible = true;
        gBxPostageDetsEU.Visible = true;
        gBxInsurance.Visible = true;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when exit button is clicked user will get a message box asking if they want to exit, if yes program closes
        DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //close program
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when exit button is clicked user will get a message box asking if they want to exit, if yes program closes
        DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to clear all infortmation entered?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            cBxTitleEu.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtFNameEu.Text = "";
            txtLastnameEu.Text = "";
            txtHouseNoEu.Text = "";
            txtPostcodeEu.Text = "";
            txtStreetEu.Text = "";
            cBxCountriesEu.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cBxWeightEU.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtKilosEu.Text = "";

            cBxTitleEu.Focus();

            cBxTitlesUk.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtFNameUk.Text = "";
            txtLNameUk.Text = "";
            txtHouseNo.Text = "";
            txtPostcode.Text = "";
            txtStreet.Text = "";
            cBxCountriesUk.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cBxWeightUk.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtKilosUk.Text = "";

            cBxTitlesUk.Focus();

        }
    }

    private void cBxWeightUk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cBxWeightUk.SelectedIndex == 5)
        {
            lblKilosUk.Visible = true;
            txtKilosUk.Visible = true;
        }
        //double weightUK = Convert.ToDouble(txtKilosUk.Text);
        //txtKilosUk.Text = Convert.ToDouble(weightUK);

        

    }

    private void cBxWeightEU_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cBxWeightEU.SelectedIndex == 5)
        {
            lblKilosEu.Visible = true;
            txtKilosEu.Visible = true;
        }

        //double weightEU = Convert.ToDouble(txtKilosEu.Text);

    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int position = postDets.weight;
        details();
        calculateTotal(position);
        Form frmDelivery = new DeliveryCost();
        frmDelivery.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void details()
    {
        if (rBtnUK.Checked == true)
        {
            postDets.UK = true;
            postDets.title = cBxTitlesUk.Text;
            postDets.fName = txtFNameUk.Text;
            postDets.sName = txtLNameUk.Text;
            postDets.houseNo = txtHouseNo.Text;
            postDets.street = txtStreet.Text;
            postDets.country = cBxCountriesUk.Text;
            postDets.postcode = txtPostcode.Text;
            postDets.weight = cBxWeightUk.SelectedIndex;
            postDets.kilos = txtKilosUk.Text;

            if (rBtnNextDay.Checked == true)
            {
                postDets.extra = 3.50;
                postDets.delSelection = "Next day selected";
            }
            else
            {
                postDets.extra = 0;
                postDets.delSelection = "Standard selected";
            }

            if (rBtnYinsurance.Checked == true)
            {
                postDets.insurance = 0.10;
                postDets.inSelection = "Insurance selected";
            }
            else
            {
                postDets.insurance = 0;
                postDets.inSelection = "Insurance not selected";
            }

        }
        else if (rBtnEU.Checked == true)
        {
            postDets.UK = false;
            postDets.title = cBxTitleEu.Text;
            postDets.fName = txtFNameEu.Text;
            postDets.sName = txtLastnameEu.Text;
            postDets.houseNo = txtHouseNoEu.Text;
            postDets.street = txtStreetEu.Text;
            postDets.country = cBxCountriesEu.Text;
            postDets.postcode = "N/A";
            postDets.weight = cBxWeightEU.SelectedIndex;
            postDets.kilos = txtKilosEu.Text;

            if (rBtnAirMail.Checked == true)
            {
                postDets.extra = 8.50;
                postDets.delSelection = "Air mail selected";
            }
            else
            {
                postDets.extra = 0;
                postDets.delSelection = "Surface mail selected";
            }

            if (rBtnYinsurance.Checked == true)
            {
                postDets.insurance = 0.10;
                postDets.inSelection = "Insurance selected";
            }
            else
            {
                postDets.insurance = 0;
                postDets.inSelection = "Insurance not selected";
            }
        }
    }

   private double calculateTotal(int position)
    {
        double price, cost;
        

        if (postDets.UK == true)
        {
            price = double.Parse(StandardUK[position]);
        }
        else
        {
            price = double.Parse(SurfaceEU[position]);
        }

       
        cost = price * postDets.insurance + postDets.extra;
        return cost;
    }
}
```

}

form 2 for outputing results

```
namespace ParcelDelivery
{
    public partial class DeliveryCost : Form
    {
    List<string> Weight = new List<string>();
    List<string> StandardUK = new List<string>();
    List<string> SurfaceEU = new List<string>();
    public DeliveryCost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("PostageCost.csv");
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
            String[] values = line.Split(',');
            Weight.Add(values[0]);
            StandardUK.Add(values[1]);
            SurfaceEU.Add(values[2]);

        }
    }
    private void btnVeiw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblNameAddDets.Text = postDets.title + " " + postDets.fName + " " + postDets.sName + "\r" + postDets.houseNo + " " + postDets.street + "\r" + postDets.country + "\r" + postDets.postcode + "\r" + postDets.weight + " Kg " + postDets.kilos + " Kilos";
        lblPostDets.Text = postDets.inSelection + "\r" + postDets.delSelection;
        lblCostResult.Text = calculateTotal();
    }

    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmSplash = new frmPDsplash();
        frmSplash.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when exit button is clicked user will get a message box asking if they want to exit, if yes program closes
        DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //close program
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

class

```
namespace ParcelDelivery
{
    class postDets
    {
 public static string title { get; set; }
    public static string fName { get; set; }
    public static string sName { get; set; }
    public static string houseNo { get; set; }
    public static string street { get; set; }
    public static string country { get; set; }
    public static string postcode { get; set; }
    public static int weight { get; set; }
    public static string kilos { get; set; }
    public static double extra { get; set; }
    public static double insurance { get; set; }
    public static string delSelection { get; set; }
    public static string inSelection { get; set; }
    public static Boolean UK { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate something, or look up a value? It seems you want the latter, so you might want to look up `Dictionary`. Also, `x == true` in an `if` statement is nonsense, and your `else` has a useless `if`. And you're putting numbers in `string`s, meaning you''l have to convert them before you can assign them to a double.

Comment: @oerkelens ive changed my code a bit and added in each form and the class.

Comment: We need an actual sample of the `PostageCost.csv` just the first 5 lines would be enough.

Comment: @iSR5 the text from the csv is above the code

Comment: @EGS99 not a good sample, missing the first line (columns).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to use the csv file as the data source of combobox.
You could try the following code:

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboCsv
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dta;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Regex re = new Regex(@"[^\d.]"); 
        double strweight = Convert.ToDouble(re.Replace(comboBox1.Text, ""));
        double strprice1 = Convert.ToDouble(re.Replace(txtprice1.Text, ""));
        double strprice2 = Convert.ToDouble(re.Replace(txtprice2.Text, ""));          
        txtcalcu1.Text = (strweight*strprice1).ToString();
        txtcalcu2.Text = (strweight*strprice2).ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dta= GetStream(@"....\xx.csv");
        comboBox1.DataSource = dta;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "weight";
    }
    public static DataTable GetStream(string FilePath)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return GetData(stream);
    }
    private static DataTable GetData(Stream stream)
    {
        using (stream)
        {
            using (StreamReader input = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("GBK")))
            {
                using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(input, true))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    //Number of fields in the first row
                    int columnCount = csv.FieldCount;
                    //Title array
                    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
                    //Add header row in loop
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(headers[i]);
                    }
                    //Add column data in a loop
                    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csv[i]))
                            {
                                dr[i] = csv[i];
                            }
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = comboBox1.Text;
        DataRow[] rows = dta.Select("weight='" + str + "'");
        foreach (var item in rows)
        {
            txtprice1.Text = item["price1"].ToString();
            txtprice2.Text = item["price2"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

My csv file:

[image: here]

The running result:

[image: here]